My screen stretches when using nvidia proprietary driver In Ubuntu 24.04
I am a beginner. I installed Ubuntu 24.04 and enabled installing proprietary driver while installing. After installation the screen is stretched. So I checked display settings and found that the software recognised 2 monitor while I have only one. So I decided to give Fedora a try but the situation is same there. After installing proprietary driver Fedora also stretched. I tried Ubuntu 22.04 and it works perfect. Can anyone guide me?
